# Flutter ListVİew always rerenders when scroll-up or scroll-down

Tags: flutter, listview, future

I've a problem with my flutter app. I just called some widgets in my listview. My widgets use Api Data(http, futurebuilder). But my widgets rerender or recall when i scroll-up or down. I call that all api methods in initstate().

I dont understand, What's the problem?

[SCREEN1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILcyU.png)

[SCREEN 2 is my problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oklle.png)

HomeScreen.dart:

```
    ...
    ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        MainHeadlineMod(),
        SizedBox(
          height: 30.0,
        ),
        CategoryMod(
          categoryId: 19,
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 30.0,
        ),
        CategoryMod(
          categoryId: 15,
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 30.0,
        ),
        CategoryMod(
          categoryId: 20,
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 30.0,
        ),
        CategoryMod(
          categoryId: 14,
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 30.0,
        ),
        CategoryMod(
          categoryId: 16,
        ),
      ],
    ),
    ...
```

CategoryMod.dart:

```
    ...
    class _CategoryModState extends State<CategoryMod> {
    final WebService ws = WebService();
    Future<List<ShortNewsModel>> _futureCategoryNews;

    @override
    void initState() {
        _futureCategoryNews = ws.fetchCategoryNews(widget.categoryId);
        super.initState();
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
        child: FutureBuilder<List<ShortNewsModel>>(
            future: _futureCategoryNews,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use Listview.builder instead of Listview.. You can avoid using FutureBuilder in this case. Give your full code if you need it be modified

Comment: Thank you for your help. I solved the problem in another way.

Comment: Is the list going to be small. What if you have this list with 100+ items.. Listview.builder will build number of items that needs to be build and it is better for performance as well

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. I used "Column()" instead of "ListView()" in "HomeScreen.dart". After that I covered Column() with SingleChildScrollView(). I think that the ListView() always rerender (*or repaint or Idk*) lists.

HomeScreen.dart:

```
    ...
    SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          MainHeadlineMod(),
          SizedBox(
            height: 30.0,
          ),
          CategoryMod(
            categoryId: 19,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 30.0,
          ),
          CategoryMod(
            categoryId: 15,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 30.0,
          ),
          CategoryMod(
            categoryId: 20,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 30.0,
          ),
          CategoryMod(
            categoryId: 14,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 30.0,
          ),
          CategoryMod(
            categoryId: 16,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    ...
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ListView cacheExtent Param (hight in px)